# Algorithmic, how to add a condition to 'and' statements?

Tags: algorithm

I have the following conditions:

```
if(a && b && c=="ok"){

}else{

}
```

but I want to check c=="ok" only if d is true , but if d is true it goes to the else.

I was thinking of `if(a && b && (c=="ok"&& d))` but I think it wont work

How can I do?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the proposed solution should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I think you want

```
if(a && b && (!d || c=="ok"))
```

if `d == true`, this is the same as

```
if(a && b && c=="ok")
```

and if `d == false`, it's the same as

```
if(a && b)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an `elseif`:

```
if(a && b && (c=="ok"&& d)) {

} elseif (d) {

}
```

Logically, there's no work-around. An else-if is necessary for this.

BTW: `a && (b && c)` is exactly the same as `a && b && c` so you don't need the braces around `c` and `d` but to me it's OK since it clarifies your intention.

Answer (score 0):

If you want else to be executed if `d` alone is true. then why complicate it with other parts?

```
if(d){
//current else part logic goes here
}else{
// do things if d is not true
}
```